# Wordpress Auth + Nonces + Ajax + No Templating - Cookie nonce is invalid

Tags: ajax, wordpress, rest, authentication, nonce

I understand the process of using nonces when I create my own templates.
But I am developing a ReactJS App which uses ONLY the Wordpress REST API for pulling data, so the user never gets to the index.php, but does Ajax calls to the WP Rest Api.

Now I cannot get the nonce stuff to work. 
This is what I have done so far:

I added the following endpoints:

```
register_rest_route('frontend', '/customer/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_customer'
));

register_rest_route('frontend', '/customer/', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'create_user_and_login'
));
```

These are my functions:

```
function get_customer()
{
    return get_current_user_id();
}


function create_user_and_login(){
    // dummy data for testing
    $credentials = ['user_login' => 'mail@mymail.de', 'user_password' => 'XXXX', 'remember' => true];

    // create a new user/customer via woocommerce
    $customerId = wc_create_new_customer($credentials['user_login'], $credentials['user_login'], $credentials['user_password']);
    if(is_a($customerId,'WP_Error')) {
        return $customerId;
    }
    // get the user & log in
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $customerId );
    if( $user ) {
        wp_set_current_user( $customerId);
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $customerId );
    }
    // create new nonce and return it
    $my_nonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
    return $my_nonce;
}
```

If I now run a POST to `/customer` which triggers `create_user_and_login()`, the newly created nonce is returned in the ajax response. Then I use the returned nonce to run my next request, a GET to `/customer?_wpnonce=MY-NONCE`, but I get the error:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce",
    "message": "Cookie nonce is invalid",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

I checked [the nonce documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) but I could not find a solution for my problem. Could it be that the sessions are out of sync? So that the nonce is created on the wrong session or `wp_set_auth_cookie` and `wp_set_current_user` are not called correctly? Or do I have to use the [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function? This will get problematic, as I want to have the ReactJS and the Wordpress backend separated.

I got two cookies after the POST, a `wordpress` cookie and a `wordpress_logged_in` cookie.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Check this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179460/extend-wordpress-4-x-session-and-nonce)

It seems that when you call `$my_nonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');` the nonce is created with the old session cookie, even when you call `wp_set_auth_cookie` and `wp_set_current_user`. But in the next request the session is updated, meaning that the nonce is wrong.

As in the answer, add the following hook (functions.php for example) to force an update of the cookie:

```
        function my_update_cookie( $logged_in_cookie ){
            $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] = $logged_in_cookie;
        }
        add_action( 'set_logged_in_cookie', 'my_update_cookie' );
```

Comment: Hello 
I have added same method and want to perform wordpress login using ajax from another site. But cookies still not set Which action to call to update cookies. I am using curl to call wordpress template file and try to login

Comment: This sounds more like a cross site cookie issue. Read more about cross site cookies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies